# Execute a Function in Silverstripe via Cronjob

Tags: php, cron, silverstripe

Hi I want to execute a function via cronjob to start an csv import. At the moment the import is triggered by accessing a controller in the browser tld.de/Update

The controller has this code http://pastie.org/8351266

How can I execute the *function init()* via Cronjob?

Thx!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In SilverStripe you can access any route that is accessible via HTTP also by running cli-script.php in the command line

There also is `sake` which is just a bash wrapper around cli-script.php (but sake needs to be installed)

so, from your project directory, you can run both commands which will perform the same action (in this case, run a dev/build):

```
php framework/cli-script.php dev/build
sake dev/build
```

see the docs for commandline ussage of silverstripe: http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/topics/commandline

---

the 2nd part of your question (how to call a method from a controller) is actually more a question of routing in silverstripe and has nothing to do with how it is called (cronjob)

I assume that your controller is a Page_Controller or a subclass of that (so bound to a SiteTree Model), then routing is done for you (it takes the URLs you set in the CMS).
so lets see some example code and lets assume you have a page with the URLSegment `about`:

```
class Page_Controller extends ContentController {
    private static $allowed_actions = array('something');
    public function init() {
        // the init method will run before every action
        // this means this code will run, no matter if you visit /about or /about/something
    }
    public function index() {
        // this is the default action (this code is optional and can be removed), 
        // and will be called if you visit website.com/about
        return $this;
    }
    public function something() {
        // this is the somethingaction, 
        // and will be called if you visit website.com/about/something
        // do something here
        return $this;
    }
}
```

you can then call run to get the result of the `index()`:

```
php framework/cli-script.php about
```

and this to get the result of `something()`:

```
php framework/cli-script.php about/something
```

**NOTE**: the init method itself is not accessable via URL, it is the "setup" that runs before an action
**NOTE**: all actions other than `index()` have to be allowed by adding them to `$allowed_actions` (also note that you need to ?flush=1 after adding to `$allowed_actions` to reload the config cache)

**EDIT**: this was actually the response to your first question, after seeing your code example, this addition:

for standalone controllers it works the same way, just that you have to define the routes, and make sure that you have `$Action` in the route so that `something()` can be called

Comment: hi zauberfisch, i tried to run a dev/build via ssh terminal like you told above but i receive the following error =>  `X-Powered-By: PHP/4.4.9
Content-type: text/html

<br />
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in <b>_testpage/framework/core/Core.php</b> on line <b>113</b><br />' if I use /usr/local/bin/php54 ... i get stuck on the login message and if I use php-cli. putty tells me that the command is not found

Comment: well, the first error message is obviously a error because of a to low php version. using a new php version like you did with php54 is the solution. But I don't understand what you mean by "stuck on the login message"

Comment: if the page is not in dev mode i receive the following output -> http://www.sspaste.com/paste/show/5256860510ca9 I think I need to login somehow, but how?

Comment: it would indeed seem that silverstripe wants you to login. if you visit /dev/build in live mode in a webbrowser this should happen, but silverstripe should actually detect that you are using cli and should bypass the login. Not sure if this is a silverstripe bug or if php is used wrongly here

Comment: Care to elaborate on that? I beg your forgiveness, but I fail to see a new point in your comment.

Answer (score 5):

You could do this without Silverstripe sake. Install curl and call the URL via a cronjob, ie:

```
0 0 * * * curl --silent http://tld.de/Update
```

The proper way to do this would be to write a Silverstripe task, and invoke your controller from within the task. I haven't tested this code but it would go something like this:

```
class YourTask extends BuildTask {
    public $description = "...";
    //...
    public function run($request) {
        YourController::init();
    }
}
```

You can invoke it over sake using:

```
0 0 * * * /path/to/framework/sake dev/tasks/YourTask
```

Answer (score 2):

why not create a build task ? which is specially designed for such requirements (at-least that's how I consider build tasks)

```
<?php
    class ArticleCsvUpdateTask extends BuildTask {

    protected $title = 'Article Csv Update';

    protected $description = 'Build task for article Csv update';

    public function run($request) {
        $loader = new ArticleCsvBulkLoader('Color');
        if($loader->load('import-new.csv')) {
            $loader->load('import-new.csv');
        } 
    }
}
```

Which can be assess both from browser using "**yoursite/dev/tasks/ArticleCsvUpdateTask**" and from command line using "**php framework/cli-script.php dev/tasks/ArticleCsvUpdateTask**" OR using "**sake dev/tasks/ArticleCsvUpdateTask**" (if you have sake installed).

May be I am not getting your exact requirement but I believe this is much cleaner and nicer way of running a cron job with silverstripe.

Answer (score 1):

**See [Zauberfisch's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18978883/836646) for a complete solution**

I'm not familiar with Silverstripe, but if I understand correctly, this controller `init` function can be called with a HTTP request.

As the silverstripe docs say, you can call any url from the command line:

```
php framework/cli-script.php Update/init
```

More information is available [here](http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/topics/commandline), and consider using `sake` for this task.

Comment: This answer is on the right track, but the init() method of controllers in silverstripe is not accessable this way, as it is the setup of the controller so to speak.

Comment: ah okay thanks, i'll test it, let's see what happens
@Zauberfisch so i just have to rename this function?

Comment: I've written a full answer, I think it should cover this question, if not, feel free to ask again

Comment: @Zauberfisch I've added a reference to your answer

Comment: a reference? I know not what you speak of

Comment: @Zauberfisch a link in my answer to yours

Answer (score 0):

I think the right way do this is create a php file console like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

require_once "/path/to/your/class/Update.php";
$class = new Update();
$class->init();
```

Add right perms to this file

```
chmod 755 consolefile
```

And finally run this script with cronjob

Comment: Hi thank you! but after executing the cronjob i receive this error 
<br />
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_OLD_FUNCTION
or T_FUNCTION or T_VAR or '}' in
<b>/kunden/xxxx/webspace/xxxx/mysite/code/Update.php</b>
on line <b>5</b><br />

Comment: How are you executing this script?

Comment: the idea would work for plain php, but with silverstripe not that easily.
SilverStripe has an autoloader, which you do not include here, so you will get an error that class Controller is not found (because Update extends Controller)
I recommend going with the silverstripe cli-script.php or sake (see my answer)

Comment: over the hoster's control-panel @zauberfisch. ok i'll try this! thanks  a lot.